# Multiple filters on jquery isotope

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to be able to select multiple filters and have the results show as such. Then, when they click show all, it removes all filters. I'm using the jquery isotope plugin.

see here: https://convention.test.yja.org/sessions

I want someone to be able to pick an age group and a category (potentially multiple age groups and multiple categories too)

here is the filter code:

```
 <ul class="filter list-inline">
    <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Education"><i class="fa fa-book" style="color:#bbbbbb"></i> Jain Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Lifestyle"><i class="fa fa-hand-holding-heart" style="color:#bbbbbb"></i> Lifestyle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Career"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" style="color:#bbbbbb"></i> Career & Networking</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".DiversityInclusion"><i class="fa fa-globe" style="color:#bbbbbb"></i> Diversity & Inclusion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".SocialIssues"><i class="fa fa-handshake" style="color:#bbbbbb"></i> Current Events & Social Issues</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="filter list-inline">
    <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".HS">High School</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".College">College</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".JNF">JNF</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the isotope js code:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
/* =  portfolio isotope
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

var winDow = $(window);
// Needed variables
var $container = $('.iso-call');
var $filter = $('.filter');

try {
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.trigger('resize');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '*',
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear'
            }
        });

        $('.triggerAnimation').waypoint(function () {
            var animation = $(this).attr('data-animate');
            $(this).css('opacity', '');
            $(this).addClass("animated " + animation);

        },
                {
                    offset: '75%',
                    triggerOnce: true
                }
        );
        setTimeout(1500);
    });
} catch (err) {
}

winDow.bind('resize', function () {
    var selector = $filter.find('a.active').attr('data-filter');

    try {
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
    }
    return false;
});

// Isotope Filter 
$filter.find('a').click(function () {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    try {
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {

    }
    return false;
});


var filterItemA = $('.filter li a');

filterItemA.on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        filterItemA.removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, that you have two click events on the same objects. `$filter.find('a').click(` and `filterItemA.on('click',`

The first one does the hard job, the second one is only makes sure there are only one button is clicked any time.

You should change the second one, to

- remove the active flags only when you click one of the `Show All` buttons,
- deactivate the `Show All`-s when clicks on anything else

And the fist one to

- compose the selector based on `filterItemA.filter(".active")`

```js
filterItemA.off('click')
filterItemA.map( (x,i) => {
    if( $(i).attr('data-filter')=="*") {
     $(i).addClass("showall")
    } else {
     $(i).addClass("noshowall")
    }
})

filterItemA.on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var selector = $this.attr('data-filter');
    var filterActive;
    var activeSelector;
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
 if (selector=="*") {
     filterItemA.filter(".noshowall").removeClass('active')
     filterItemA.filter(".showall").addClass('active')
 } else {
     filterItemA.filter(".showall").removeClass('active')
     $this.addClass('active')
 }
    } else {
 if (selector=="*") {
  // select show all... what to do here?
 } else {
     $this.removeClass('active')
     filterActive=filterItemA.filter(".noshowall.active")
     activeSelector = Array.join(filterActive.map( (x,i) => $(i).attr("data-filter")),'')
     if (activeSelector== "") { 
  filterItemA.filter(".showall").addClass("active")
     }

 }
    }
    filterActive=filterItemA.filter(".noshowall.active")
    activeSelector = Array.join(filterActive.map( (x,i) => $(i).attr("data-filter")),'')
    if (activeSelector== "") { activeSelector="*"; }
    try {
 $container.isotope({
     filter: activeSelector,
     animationOptions: {
  duration: 750,
  easing: 'linear',
  queue: false
     }
 });
    } catch (err) {
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: awesome! will try this out. also, i'm not sure if you noticed - but I have the same filters at the top and bottom of the page - is there a way to sync them?

Comment: hmm, when I do what you said, everything goes away when I click on a filter. would you be able to post the code? @n3ko